# Cannot delete own file on Win7

Tags: windows-7, permissions

I've accidentally created a file on a network share. Now I want to delete it.

When I attempt to do so I get the error message that I need permission from `EAST1\perterh` (=myself) in order to delete it. I'm attempting to delete from the same File Explorer session where I accidentally created the file.

If I right-click the file, choose Properties --> Security --> Advanced, it says I'm the owner of the file. This is no surprise as I just created it. Also I have all possible permissions on the file.

I'm assuming - help me out here, I'm a Unix/Linux guy - that the problem is related to the enclosing folder, not the individual file. But the error message is strange. How can I grant myself permission ?

How to get rid of this file ?

(and yes, I've trawled many posts on somewhat similar issues)

#### Additional info:

Output from `icacls` :

```
New Text Document.txt EAST1\GB32ADH3_Admin:(I)(F)
                      BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
                      NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
                      EAST1\peterh:(I)(F)
                      BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
```

Output from `dir /q "New Text Document.txt"` :

```
09-09-2016  08:31                 0 EAST1\peterh            New Text Document.txt
```

Output from `ver` command:

```
Microsoft Windows [version 6.1.7601]
```

(Citrix session on Windows 2008)

Output from `TAKEOWN` command:

```
takeown /F "New Text Document.txt"
ERROR: The current logged on user does not have ownership privileges on
    the file (or folder) "New Text Document.txt".
```

Output from `whoami` command:

```
EAST1\peterh
```

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include the output of `icacls` and `dir /q` for the file in question?

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan. Done!

Comment: most common for this type of problem is an open session. Reboot your pc or linux first.  Sometimes may need to powerdown for 12 seconds depending on type of file server y'all use.

Comment: By my interpretation of the output of those commands, the file is owned by you and you have *Full Permissions* (which you inherited from the containing directory) so there shouldn't be a problem. I'm more experienced with Unix but bvaughn's suggestion makes sense. Try running `whoami`; it should print `EAST1\peterh`. (By the way, that’s a good question and deserves an upvote. Welcome to [se]).

Comment: @bvaughn.Can't do that. I'm inside Citrix. I've tried closing down the Citrix session and starting a new session. Didn't help. Also the error message, that I need permission, doesn't suggest the problem is a lock but a lack of permission.